# How to clear label when clicking button?

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress

I have inputfields that calculates and shows in an ! But when I want to go to the next page (to do a new calculation) my code only clears the inputfields and not the label where de result is shown. The code I have is shown down under..

```
    <td>
    <label class="o-money__totalsum" type="number" onfocus="this.value=''" step="1" name="total-<?php echo $counter;?>" id="total-<?php echo $counter;?>">0 SEK
    </label>
    </td>

    function resetFields(){
    $("o-exercise__button").click(function(){
        $(".o-money__answer").val(''); <- my inputfields
        $(".o-money__totalsum").val(''); <- the label!
    });

}
```

Comment: $(".o-money__totalsum").text(' ');

Comment: `.val()` is for value attributes, use `.text()` instead for your label

Comment: `label` should not be used as `input` fields, as we have `input` elements. :)

Comment: It didnt work! Just tried it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.text()` to clear it , as mentioned in the comment `.val()` is the value attributes,
in the snippet below i used a `onclick` event to trigger it

```js
    $(".o-exercise__button").on('click',function(){
        $(".o-money__answer").val(''); 
        $(".o-money__totalsum").text(''); 
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td>
<label class="o-money__totalsum" type="number" onfocus="this.value=''" step="1" name="total-<?php echo $counter;?>" id="total-<?php echo $counter;?>">0 SEK
</label>
<button class="o-exercise__button">Click</button>
</td>
```

Comment: Doesn't work! My button is an organism, I must have the class-name for it as i use it above.

Comment: @TempestNorlin I did edit my answear using your class button